# How to give different permissions to multiple groups of users?

Tags: permissions

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 server and want to give full folder access say example: "Folder01" to group "Group01' and Limit "Group02" for read access only. How I can do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to restrict access to only two groups (say Group01 full access and Group02 having only read only access) you can use file access control lists (ACLs). (In your case I think it's the  best solution)

```
setfacl -R -m g:Group01:rwx Folder01
setfacl -R -m g:Group02:r-- Folder01
```

You can verify changes via `getfacl Folder01` and you can remove others' permissions by running `chmod -R o-rwx Folder01`

This way your folder is only accessible via Group01 ( full access ) and Group02 (read only access) and no doubt the owner of that folder can also access it.