# linux I want to add permission on two groups

Tags: server, permissions, chmod, groups

I have my owner (`Pierre`) and he has all  permission on `g586` folder, I have my first group (`G586`) have read permission, I have another groupe name (`teacher`) have read and execute permission, and other have no permission.

I have link `Pierre` as the owner of the folder, `G586` as the group,
I do a `chmod 710` on my `g586` folder, now I want to know how to add the right for the group `teacher`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give different permissions to multiple groups of users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352298/how-to-give-different-permissions-to-multiple-groups-of-users)

Answer (score 2):

With UNIX permissions, every file or directory can only have one group, so if the group of the directory is `g586`, you cannot define permissions for group `teacher`.

One option would be to add user `Pierre` to group `teacher` as a supplementary group and use group `teacher` for the directory. Maybe you need to set the `setgid` bit for the directory to make sure all new files will belong to the same group.